# Determine the difference between correlation coefficients

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, regression-coefficients

I know the procedure how to test the statistical significance of the difference between correlation coefficients for two groups. The method I am familiar with is by converting each of the r values into z values, and put them into an equation to calculate Zobs (observed value of z-score).

How do we proceed in the case of 4 groups?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend testing group differences in a single model (incidentally, I would suggest this approach for the difference between two correlation coefficients you describe as well).

To do so you will have to create a set of dummy variables to represent your categorical predictor. 
[Click for an explanation on how to do this in SPSS](http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/multibook/mlt08m.html)

Next you should mean center your continuous predictor. Finally, you should create a set of new terms that represent the products of this newly created mean-centered continuous predictor and each of the dummy variables you have created.

Finally, place the dummy variables, the mean-centered continuous predictor, and the resulting interaction terms in a single model and regress them on the outcome variable of interest. Significant interaction terms will indicate that the strength of the association between the continuous predictor and the outcome variable differs between the reference group and the target group indicated by the relevant dummy variable.

Comment: I am curious to know what it implies if the correlation coefficient R between two different groups significant or non-significant. What additional info does that provide while reporting our regression analysis?

Comment: If I understand your question it means that the strength of the relation between the two variables in question in a given group is significantly different from the strength of the relation between the two variables in the reference group. This would appear in the model as a significant interaction term.